# How can I associate numbers with strings?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have made a tableview; in that tableview I have made two NSArray: one is for Numbers and the other is for countries.

When the View loads up, numbers are displayed from the array like 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.
When the user select any number from that list, the respective countries should be displayed like: 1 is for India, 2 is for china, etc.
How can I display them? please help me.

Comment: `NSDictionary` could be a solution. Or using the `indexPath` (`UITableView`) side and `index` (`NSArray` side).

Comment: I'm pretty sure you asked this question a few minutes ago, although I can't find it. First of all your question title does not match what you are asking at all, you are not copying anything from anywhere. It sounds as though you are trying to use the value form array A (numbers) as the index for array B (country). I would question why you simply can't simply use the one array. You need to clarify your issue

Comment: Your title has no relation to your question, copy what to what? Anyway you could use an NSDictionary, or you could use the row selection number from the selected table view cell as the index into the country array provided they  sorted in the same order you require. Or as Simon says why not just have one array of countries, what is the point of having an array of numbers at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make an association, you need a data structure that associates.  A dictionary does this, but is unordered.  So to have an ordered association, you need an array of two-member arrays.

However, numbers are a special case, since array positions are implicitly numbered.  You can associate numbers (scalars) with strings just with an array of strings:

```
NSArray *strings = @[@"associated with zero", @"associated with one" /* etc*/];
```

To go from some int to a string, you can say: `strings[someInt];` and to go from some string to an int, you can say: `[strings indexOfObject:someString];`

For NSNumbers, just convert to scalar `intValue` or from scalar `numberWithInt:`